# How can I install Fritz 16 on a Mac running macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, applications, windows, mojave, wine

I'm new to Apple's ecosystem, and I have one doubt about how to install one software that I had in my old Windows computer.

The software is Fritz 16 (chess software), but it is not supported on macOS.

Is there any way to install it using Wine, or something similar?

Comment: Another option is to install a virtualization program like VMWare Fusion or Oracle VirtualBox, install a full Windows install on it, set it up minimally, and install your game on it.  It will never perform as well as if it were running natively, and you might have issues with intercepted keystrokes or clicks.  But the programs are more likely to start and run than with Wine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a repository of the state of Wine support for a lot of applications on https://www.winehq.com. The entry for Fritz is [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1139).

PS: Current state of support deliberately not included in the answer because it can change anytime.